# Adding a Row between the List View and the AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to place a Row between the

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Text("Header")
            ],
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: verses.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(verses[i].verseText),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

But it throws the following error,

> The following assertion was thrown during layout: A RenderFlex
>   overflowed by 1917 pixels on the bottom.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap listView with Expanded like this:

```
Expanded (
  child: ListView.buider(...)
)
```